# Prevent the serialization of a specific field with protocol buffers

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

I've been considering using .proto files as definition of my components in an entity-systems architecture.

It will keep things simple for network serialization of my components but i have one request :
Is it possible to prevent a field from being serialized ?

An example would be a Position component having the properties x, y, oldx, oldy. I might need oldx and oldx for different purposes but i wouldn't necessarily want those fields to be serialized if they are not used on the other side of the network.

I need the flexibility of the .proto files so inheriting from the generated class would defy the purpose of what i want to do here. Maybe i could do something at the protoc level ?

Comment: What client library / language / framework are you using?

Comment: Javascript with [this non-official protobuf version](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js).

Comment: Ultimately, this is a library thing; you would have to consult the documentation for that specific library, but the feature isn't guaranteed to exist (you could of course write it). For reference, it does exist in protobuf-net, but that won't help you in the least, since that isn't javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I might write my own thing then. So you confirm that this is not possible via the .proto file !?

Comment: Correct; this is not something that is a part of the specification

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you can specify a message fields as `"optional"` in the .proto file.

[you can read more here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) under Specifying Field Rules section.